# Execution terminating after 1 minute of delay

Tags: java, asynchronous, intellij-idea, google-drive-api, okhttp

Here is a REST client code which is uploading a file to a Google drive asynchronously using CompletableFuture and okhttp's enqueue method-

```
class GoogleDriveClient {
    private static String GDRIVE_METADATA_BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files";
    private static String GDRIVE_FILE_BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files";
    private static final String BEARER_TOKEN = "ya29.a0AfB_byAMRXUSSIKjn10pIWLecuFGOwdxpn1OML3zs2dSjZxxSDBCz5sDcGrtlS935pkBp_MwnhwE7YskL5CaFpmWzUrx6k_ynvE8yqnt2CRo01ACk_2fcCZAdzdrQVd5V6oys88O-9zVXBhrRvhEIE7410sFf01hANKnbQaCgYKATsSARASFQHsvYlssCibTKLmy1KIRVwL9Cr7Vw0173";

    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


    public CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> createFile(File file) {
        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> futureHttpResponse = new CompletableFuture<>();

        String metadata = "{\"name\": \"" + file.getName() + "\"}";

        RequestBody metadataBody = RequestBody.create(metadata, MediaType.parse("application/json"));
        RequestBody fileDataBody = RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream")); //application/octet-stream

        MultipartBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addPart(metadataBody)
                .addPart(fileDataBody)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(GDRIVE_FILE_BASE_URL + "?uploadType=multipart")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + BEARER_TOKEN)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new HttpResponseCallback(futureHttpResponse));

        return futureHttpResponse;
    }

    private static class HttpResponseCallback implements Callback {
        private final CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> futureHttpResponse;

        public HttpResponseCallback(CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> futureHttpResponse) {
            this.futureHttpResponse = futureHttpResponse;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            futureHttpResponse.completeExceptionally(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful())
                System.out.println("Response not successful");
            else {
                futureHttpResponse.complete(new HttpResponse(response.code(), response.body().string()));
                System.out.println("Response successful");
            }
        }
    }


}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        GoogleDriveClient googleDriveClient = new GoogleDriveClient();

        String filePath = "C:\\Files\\sample.bat";
        File newFile = new File(filePath);
        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> future = googleDriveClient.createFile(newFile);
        HttpResponse response = future.get();
        System.out.println(response.getCode());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

The problem is that its uploading a file successfully but the execution is not terminating after uploading the file. Its terminating after 1 minute or so.

I Tried to close the client connection but its of no use. Am I missing something or anything I am not aware of? Please help. Thank you.